# OData: Could not find a property named on inherited type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

For my example, I have two classes

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Location
{
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankSortCode { get; set; }
}
```

In my query, I am returning all the locations and customers.

```
http://localhost:80/odata/Location?select=Id,Name,Town
```

However if I try to select anything in the customer (edit: So I want all locations, but bank account numbers if the location is also a customer), I get an error.

```
http://localhost:80/odata/Location?select=Id,Name,Town,BankAccountNumber

"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'BankAccountNumber' on type 'MyNamespace.Location'."
```

Is there any way to select the field in inheriting types, without selecting all? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show us, how you have configured your OData EndPoints in your webapi config and how your Dbcontext looks like? Maybe we can find something there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [OData.org](http://www.odata.org/blog/enhancing-odata-support-for-querying-derived-types/), there are 2 options to query a derived type:

1. `~/Location!Customer/`
2. `~/Location/OfType('Customer')`

So your query should look like this:

```
http://localhost:80/odata/Location!Customer?select=Id,Name,Town,BankAccountNumber
```

or

```
http://localhost:80/odata/Location/OfType('Customer')?select=Id,Name,Town,BankAccountNumber
```

/EDIT:
QianLi pointed out, that the above blog entry refers to OData V2. In Odata4 inherited types are accessed in the following syntax:

```
http://host/service/BaseType/Model.SubType
```

Reference: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793786

Comment: Its in the documentation, but Web Api doesn't seem to have this implemented. I get 404 errors on both these methods. :(

Comment: Do you have Customer defined as an enetity type? If so, try calling /Customer/?select ... instead of /Location?select...

Comment: @Serv The blog you referred is for OData V2 and inheritance is not well supported. And the `OfType` in that blog actually is a custom operation and that's the reason it cannot work.

Comment: @QianLi. Right, missed that.

Comment: Posting this as a reference that fixed my issue: **ensure your access modifiers on the property are set to public**. In my case I had `public string Something { get; protected set; }`

Answer (score 2):

You should add not only the Type name but also the namespace of the type.
For example:
`http://services.odata.org/TripPinWebApiService/People('russellwhyte')/Trips(1001)/PlanItems/ODataSamples.WebApiService.Models.Flight?$select=StartsAt`

The type Flight inherits from the type PlanItem. And `ODataSamples.WebApiService.Models` is the namespace.

More detailed information of derived type, you can refer to http://www.odata.org/getting-started/advanced-tutorial/ with some live example if you find the [spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-4-0/) too long to read...

Comment: Thanks for this. It does seem that it excludes PlanItems that are not flights though. Is it not possible to include non-flight items in the query? My question in this context would be to get the StartAt, and the SeatNumber for all items (but SeatNumber would be null/missing on Event).

Comment: I understand your question now. I don't know for sure, but I think such request can not get directly through an OData request. 1) In my opinion, it seems not a good model to request both base properties and derived properties based on the base type. To be more clear, if the property A and B are requested in `../BaseType/$select=A,B`, then `A` and `B` should both in BaseType. 2) If you do need that capability, you may write a customer function to make it work.